Number of pair of quadratic residues $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $|x-y|=4$, where $n$ is an square free positive integer.
Let $n=p_1p_2\dots p_r$ be a positive integer such that each $p_i$ is a distinct prime. Let $Q=\{x^2 : x\in \mathbb{Z}_n\}$ be the set of quadratic residue $\mod n$.
Let $Q_s=\{(x,y)\in Q\times Q : |x-y|=s\}$. What will be the cardinality of $|Q_s|$, in particular, I am interested in the cardinality of $|Q_4|$.
From the definition, $|Q_1|$ is simply the number of consecutive quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, which I could find for prime $n$ but not for the general $n$.
Any help or a reference to some book\article would be highly appreciated.

Please state your solution to $Q_1$ for prime $n$, and why you're unable to extend it to general $n$ (or at least prime power $n$). After that, show how you've tried to extend it to $Q_4$ for prime $n$.
